# unsafe type casting between wrappers types

Tags: rust, wrapper, unsafe, raw-pointer

```rust
struct Wrapper1(u32);

impl Wrapper1 {
    fn inner(&self) -> &u32 {
        &self.0
    }
}

struct Wrapper2(u32);

struct Wrapper3(Wrapper1);

trait GetInner {
 fn inner(&self) -> &Wrapper2;
}

impl GetInner for Wrapper3 {
    fn inner(&self) -> &Wrapper2 {
     let raw_pointer = self.0.inner() as *const u32 as *const Wrapper2;
     unsafe {  &*raw_pointer }
    }
}
```

I have this snippet of code showcasing a simplification of my problem.
I have to rely on `unsafe` because I cannot just do this:

```rust
impl GetInner for Wrapper3 {
    fn inner(&self) -> &Wrapper2   
      &Wrapper2(*self.0.inner())
    }
}
```

Is it sound? Somebody in my team raised concern about alignment.
Somebody else mention we have to use `#[repr(transparent)]` on the wrappers types in order to make it more safe.

Comment: You definitely have to use `#[repr(transparent)]` on such types in general. In the specific case of `u32` it seems pretty unlikely (although technically possible) that the compiler will generate different layouts. For types with niches it may do "weird" things even for simple cases. Don't risk it, use `#[repr(transparent)]`

Comment: `For types with niches it may do "weird" things even for simple cases. ` Can you expand on this and share some links regarding this phenomenon?

To sum up your point:
- it will be sound if I use `#[repr(transparent)]`
- it may cause undefined behaviours if I don't (especially for more complex inner types)

Answer (score 0):

You need `Wrapper2` to be `#[repr(transparent)]` or `#[repr(C)]`. Layout of `#[repr(Rust)` structs is not guaranteed.

However, if you do that, you don't need unsafe anymore - you can use [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck):

```rust
struct Wrapper1(u32);

impl Wrapper1 {
    fn inner(&self) -> &u32 {
        &self.0
    }
}

#[derive(bytemuck::TransparentWrapper)]
#[repr(transparent)]
struct Wrapper2(u32);

struct Wrapper3(Wrapper1);

trait GetInner {
    fn inner(&self) -> &Wrapper2;
}

impl GetInner for Wrapper3 {
    fn inner(&self) -> &Wrapper2 {
        bytemuck::TransparentWrapper::wrap_ref(self.0.inner())
    }
}
```